# Woocommerce: How to remove category on ALL pages

Tags: woocommerce

I am using Woocommerce in combination with Booked to make paid reservations for our Escape Rooms. The products that i sell are just the different booking options such as: Room A | 4 Persons | €50

When making a reservation (buying the woocommerce product) it automatically shows "Category: No category". I don't want that because when people click the "no category" they get to see the categorypage that i don't use. The pages "shop" and "all products" are also not used for my purpose.

How can i remove the categories from the following pages?: Cart, Checkout

Picture of the Cart

[image: Picture of the Cart]

Picture of the Checkout

[image: Picture of the Checkout]

Is it possible to add some lines in the Functions.php of the theme which makes the categories disappear? I already added some 3 lines that hide three columns (download-remaining, download-product and download-expires) and it works perfect for my purpose!

Here is the code i have used (copied from another article ;))

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_account_downloads_columns', 
'custom_downloads_columns', 10, 1 ); // Orders and account
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_downloads_columns', 
'custom_downloads_columns', 10, 1 ); // Email notifications
function custom_downloads_columns( $columns ){
// Removing "Download expires" column
if(isset($columns['download-expires']))
    unset($columns['download-expires']);

// Removing "Download remaining" column
if(isset($columns['download-remaining']))
    unset($columns['download-remaining']);

if(isset($columns['download-product']))
    unset($columns['download-product']);

return $columns;
}
```

This is the website: https://escape-outdoor.nl

Comment: We can help you better if you share the url of the site, so we can see some code.

Comment: Sorry for not sharing the url. I've edited the question and the url is now visible.

Comment: Hopefully someone can help me with this question. I don't think it is very difficult but i simply don't have enough knowledge.